# Is there a better approach to the proof code of "100 prisoners" question?

Tags: python

Well, I'm quite a beginner and need some help and advice. Sometime ago i watched this video about [100 prisoners question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20case%20that%20one,of%20length%20at%20most%2050.) and wanted to write a proof program to see if the ratio really approaches to ~30%. But i got ~12%. I couldnt really find out where I did mistakes. Here is my code:

```
import random
from statistics import mean

prisoners = []
box_dict = {}
saved_prisoners = []
counter = 0
average = []

for i in range(1, 101):
            prisoners.append(i)

for i in range(1000):
    def control_list_generation():        

        for i in range(100):
            x = random.sample(prisoners, 1)
            y = x[0]
            box_dict[i] = y


    control_list_generation()


    def open_box():
        global saved_prisoners
        global counter
        counter = 0

        for prisoner in range(100):
            counter = prisoner
            for turn in range(50):
                if box_dict.get(counter) == (prisoner + 1):
                    saved_prisoners.append(1)
                    break
                else:
                    counter = box_dict.get(counter) - 1
                    continue


    open_box()

    average.append(len(saved_prisoners))
    saved_prisoners.clear()

print(mean(average))
```

P.S. range on the 13th line can be changed

Comment: @MichaelButscher i deleted random.sample line and put random.shuffle in between for loops and in the second for loop i assign them into the box_dict. Was this what you meant?

Comment: @code_noah Yes, I meant that.

Comment: @natio2 although you're not wrong that pseudorandom isn't truly random, it won't affect problems like these, at least not in any meaningful way. True randomness is important in some situations, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of superfluous lines. Just by editing out anything unneeded, you can end up with:

```
import random
from statistics import mean

prisoners = list(range(1, 101))
box_dict = {}
saved_prisoners = []
counter = 0
average = []

for i in range(1000):
    for i in range(100):
        x = random.sample(prisoners, 1)
        y = x[0]
        box_dict[i] = y

    counter = 0

    for prisoner in range(100):
        counter = prisoner
        for turn in range(50):
            if box_dict.get(counter) == (prisoner + 1):
                saved_prisoners.append(1)
                break
            else:
                counter = box_dict.get(counter) - 1
                continue

    average.append(len(saved_prisoners))
    saved_prisoners.clear()

print(mean(average))
```

However, you just use the `dict` more or less as a new list (the indices amount to the same as just shuffling the prisoners in a list). And when constructing it, you're accidentally duplicating prisoner tickets by sampling from the same prisoners over and over. (as user @MichaelButscher correctly points out in the comments)

If you fix those issues, your code still doesn't quite work because you have some further mistakes and moving around of numbers in your box checking.

Here's a solution that follows the pattern of your code, but shows the problem correctly:

```
import random

n_prisoners = 100
prisoners = list(range(n_prisoners))
boxes = []
failures = 0
attempts = 1000


for i in range(attempts):
    boxes = list(prisoners)
    random.shuffle(boxes)

    for prisoner in prisoners:
        box_nr = prisoner
        for turn in range(n_prisoners // 2):
            if boxes[box_nr] == prisoner:
                break
            box_nr = boxes[box_nr]
        else:
            failures += 1
            break

print(f'{failures / attempts * 100}% of attempts failed')
```

Example output:

```
70.3% of attempts failed
```

As a general tip: don't get too hung up on numbering stuff from 1 instead of 0. That caused several coding mistakes in your code, because you kept having to correct for 'off by one' problems. Simply numbering the prisoners from 0 to 99 is far simpler, as it allows you to use the prisoner's number as an index. In case you need to print their number and need that to start at 1 - *that* would be the time to offset by one, not everywhere in your logic.

Comment: Thx a lot. Im pretty new to coding and I will definitely study your code. much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome - please feel free to ask for clarification if the answer isn't clear, or you can't figure out why some part of it works.